# Firestore index merging performance with imbalanced data sets

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The Google Cloud documentation goes into a great amount of detail about the tradeoffs between merging single-property indexes vs. using composite indexes.

On this [page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/optimize-indexes#:%7E:text=the%20smallest%20set%20of%20potential%20entities%20from%20a%20single%20index%20scan.) it says:

> The best-case performance of an index merge happens when every potential match in an index satisfies the query filters. In this case, performance is O(R * I) where R is the size of the result set and I is the number of indexes scanned.

> The worst-case performance happens when the database must consider many potential matches but few of them satisfy the query filters. In this case, performance is O(S) where S is the size of the smallest set of potential entities from a single index scan.

So for example if the query is: `db.collection('employees').where('department','==','accounting').where('diploma','==','CPA')` and we assume all employees in accounting hold a CPA, then this is the best case performance (all potential matches are in the result set), and if we assume there are 5 such employees, performance is 10 (R = 5 and I = 2 corresponding to the two `where` clauses).

On the other hand, if the query is: `db.collection('athletes').where('country','==','jamaica').where('sport','==','bobsleigh')` we are closer to worst-case performance given there are many Jamaican athletes and also many bobsleighers but few people who meet both criteria. In this case, is S the number of athletes in Jamaica? Or the number of bobsleighers in the world? Or the smallest of the two, as is implied by the documentation, which is still large? Anyway in this case we would definitely want a composite index.

Finally, this is the case I am unsure of: `db.collection('novels').where('author','==','stephen king').where('in-print','==',true)`:
the set of novels matching the author is about 65, a moderate number, but the set of books still in print is gigantic, many million. In addition we can assume most of Stephen King's novels are still in print. In this case, will index merging lead to good performance based on the small first set (65) or poor performance due to the large second set (many million)? If performance is poor, I would create a composite index, but the composite index is not needed if the zigzag algorithm can somehow return the 65 books without browsing through the millions of in-print entries.

In addition, would performance of index merging change if we change the order of the constraints: `db.collection('novels').where('in-print','==',true).where('author','==','stephen king')` e.g. if firestore now needs to browser through the millions of in-print novels to find the ones by this author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third case:

```
db.collection('novels').where('author','==','stephen king').where('in-print','==',true):
```

If the `author` clause leads to 65 items,and the `in-print` leads to millions, the performance will depends on the `author` clause as that is "the smallest set of potential entities from a single index".

So if you're looking for which queries to optimize with a composite index, look for queries where the potential entities that match each clause are large. Creating a composite index for those fields/clauses will put the potential results that match all clauses closer together in that index, which allows the database to find them more easily/faster.

Comment: Thanks! in other words, in this particular example, as 65 is small and the millions are irrelevant to performance, a composite index wouldn't be needed then.